# Automation of a graphical app in a windows VM

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, ui-automation

I need to automate a windows only java graphical app in a cloud vm.

I'm currently trying with windwos server 2008 and robotJS in node, if I'm connected to the VM in RDP and showing the screen, all is good and it work, but it's no real automation.

If managed to launch the user session at start, and added the app and my script in the startup dire to have them launched when the user logon, but when I do that, the robot only see a black screen with the start button when I'm taking a screenshot, and it can't interact with the app.

As someone already try to do that ?
Any insight would be good, I can change the server version, use another automation tool, anything if it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I let that here because it might one day help someone.

The trick was to use keyboard shortcut instead of mouse, not sure why.